# Selenium moveToElement() to read the tool tip is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After adding an invalid file type to file upload section a validation message will be displayed as a ToolTip, I am not able to validate the ToolTip even after using moveToElement();

Here is the code that I used to make the tooltip visible

```
`driver.findElement(By.xpath(""//input[@type='file']"").sendKeys(invalidLicenseFileType.txt);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(//*[contains(@class, 'fieldlabel-content')]).build().perform();`
```

[image: ToolTip validation message image]

HTML Code:

```
<div class="fieldlabel-content">
    <label class="fileinput fileinput--invalid">
    <div class="fileinput-cell fileinput-cell-input">
    <input placeholder="Choose a .license file..." accept=".license" value="" tabindex="0" type="file">
    <div class="fileinput-description">
    File:
    <span class="fileinput-description-file">
    <span class="icon fa fa-file-text-o"></span>
    invalidLicenseFileType.txt
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "popup popup--theme-error popup--position-top popup--hover" style="top: 131px; left: 399px;">Validation message for uploading invalid file type.</div>
    </label>
```

Comment: Could you show us the HTML?

Comment: @BuabanI have added the HTML to the question

Comment: Can you give us the error message and more java code before the action?

Comment: @Buaban the Java code performed before the action is doing .sendkeys("File name") to add the file. Immediately after the file is added I am getting the validation message.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add those code? So we can investigate.

Comment: added the selenium steps that I am performing

Comment: Tooltip is something that appears along with the mouse pointer when you hoover on an particular element.

Comment: @santhoshkumar that's the reason I used moveToElement()

Comment: So, move to is working fine and the message is visible now but not able to get the content of the message in order to validate?

Comment: move to is not working so I am not able to see the validation message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing the following code help fixing my issue.

```
 try 
 {
     String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover',true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript,uploadFileInputFieldWebElement);
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     invalidLicenseFileTypeMessag = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;",tooltipWebElement);


} catch (Exception e) {
    exception message;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions to solve this problem :

**`First : Using JavaScript`**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("value of xpath")).sendKeys(invalidLicenseFileType.txt);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].onmouseover()", element);
```

In the last line, in place of `element` , you can give the `xpath of your WebElement` over which you want to hover.

**`Second : Using Actions`**

Try using **`clickAndHold`** in place of **`moveToElement`** in Actions class.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("value of xpath")).sendKeys(invalidLicenseFileType.txt);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.clickAndHold(//*[contains(@class, 'fieldlabel-content')]).build().perform();
```

Comment: I tried both the options still I not able to focus the element and due to that I am not able to get the tooltip text from the hidden element

Comment: Ok, check for any frame change or page change in your html

Comment: There is no frame or page change is happening as we input the file and if the file type is invalid immediately I will get the validation message as a tooltip. The tooltip div is hidden until I mouse over on the input file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem is the action try to hover mouse on the element, but the element is not displayed yet.
Can you try code below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']").sendKeys("invalidLicenseFileType.txt");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions. presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".popup--theme-error")));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement("//*[contains(@class, 'fileinput-description-file')]").perform();
```

Comment: It is not able to perform the mouseover function on the element

Comment: @SujaiKrishna Can it moveToElement `<span class="fileinput-description-file">`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can see some mistakes in your code.

**Code:**

```js
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("invalidLicenseFileType.txt");
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'fieldlabel-content')]"));
actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
String toolTipText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'popup popup--theme-error')]")).getText();
System.out.println("Tool tip text present :- " + toolTipText);

// Compare tool tip text
Assert.assertEquals("Validation message for uploading invalid file type.", toolTipText);
```

Comment: I am using exactly the same code as what you have provided in my project. For some reason, the moveToElement() function isn't working and because of that, the hidden element is not found while the test is running so the tooltip text is not being retrieved.

Comment: Did you exactly copy the code I have provided and tried again. It should work. I can see some mistakes in the code you have provided. Some syntax issues.

Comment: Yes, I am using the exact same code as what you provided, but in 2 different methods. Method 1 is for sending the file and in Method 2 I am doing the moveToElement and retrieving the tooltip text.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Sorry Monika, due to security reason I won't be able to share the URL